# Aggregate points with same values to polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon, point

I have a shapefile with 2M measurement points (each measurement point has a resolution of a 1/10). **How can I aggregate points around each other if and create polygons out of it?**

They do not have to match a grid, polygons should not overlap. 
In addition, I would like to reduce the resolution, e.g. aggregate all points around a 1/2 resolution.

Can I do this with QGIS or in PostGIS?

I have tried `convex hull`, but it seems that the polygons overlapped. Also, some answers are referring to ArcGIS 10, which I do not have.

Comment: how about creating a Voronoi diagram which can then be dissolved?

Comment: How can I adjust the resolution with the Voronoi diagrams?

Comment: The only way this problem makes sense to me is if the measurement value is related to the position such that points near each other tend to have similar/related values. (If the point value is unrelated to position, then I see no hope in aggregating them into polygons). If my interpretation is correct, why not just use a contour finding routine as if the data were a DEM or something similar? Generate iso-value lines at multiples of .5 and create the corresponding polygons.

Answer (score 2):

Without using a grid, it's going to be quite hard to avoid overlaps without using a Voronoi approach. You can ST_Collect them and then pass them to ST_ConcaveHull if you have a recent PostGIS. That will produce a result close to what you want, but without a "no overlap" guarantee.